# Why is $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1/\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm a beginner in Calculus and I'm studying L'Hospital's Rule.

I have to calculate the following limit: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{x}$$.

My solutions manual presents the following equation:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1/\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1}$$

While applying L'Hospital's Rule, I understand that the derivative of $x$ is $1$, but I can't figure out why the derivative of $1/\sin x$ would be $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$. I would rather think [this should be the result.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%201%2Fsenx)

Any explanations for this?

Comment: $\sin^{-1}x$ is not $1/\sin x$; rather it is the solution to $\sin y=x$ between $\pm\pi/2$.

Comment: ^^ in addition $\sin^{-1} x$ can also be called $\arcsin x$ and it is [the inverse sin function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSine.html). It's derivative is given by $$ \frac{d}{dx} [ \sin^{-1} x] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Notation

Comment: Thank you! Now it's clear. Just a notation issue. Actually it's arcsinx and not 1/sinx. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Notation

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that $\sin^{-1}(x)$ generally refers to what is often known as $\arcsin(x)$. From there, I think the only thing you are missing is why 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
I'll assume you are familiar with implicit differentiation. Set $\arcsin(x)=y$. Then $\sin(y)=x$. We have 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\sin(y)=\frac{d}{dx}(x)$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}\cos(y)=1$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\cos (y)}.$$
Now, $\cos^2y+\sin^2y=1$. Substituting, we have 
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 (y)}}.$$
Using the identities from the beginning, we have 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
as desired.

Comment: I think it's bette to always discuss the range and domains while making changes, because otherwise, the same logic will lead to other solutions (e.g. why we take the positive one when we do sqrt?)

Comment: Yes, I have been a little bit lazy. I'm in the middle of something right now. Feel free to edit, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

This is inverse notation:

$$f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$

If $f(x)$ is bijective/one-to-one.

By chain rule, when $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$:

$$x=\sin(\sin^{-1}(x))$$

$$1=\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))(\sin^{-1}(x))'$$

$$(\sin^{-1}(x))'=\frac1{\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))}\\=\frac1{\sqrt{1-(\sin(\sin^{-1}(x)))^2}}\\=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Where I use the Pythagorean theorem.

---

However, more easily, note that by letting $x=\sin u$, we get:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x}x=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}(\sin(u))}{\sin u}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac u{\sin u}=1$$

And by direct substitution, the second limit follows.

Answer (score 2):

So $\sin ^{-1} x \ne (\sin x)^{-1}$, but it means inverse mapping, i.e. if $y= \sin(x)$, then we say $x=\sin^{-1} y$

Here, we need to be careful about the **domain and range** when defining those mappings and deriving the derivative, because $\sin x$ is not a bijection - as a matter of fact, we only define $\sin^{-1} x$ over $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Let $y=\sin^{-1}x: [-1,1] \mapsto [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so $x=\sin y$. Thus

$$1=\cos y \cdot y'$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{\cos y}$$

But if $x=\sin y$, we have $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos y$, because $\cos y \ge0$ for $y \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Thus

$$y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\sin^{-1}x$ is used to mean the inverse sine function, whereas $(\sin(x))^{-1}$ is used to mean $1/\sin x$.  To avoid ambiguity, $\arcsin x$ is often used for the inverse sine function.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^{-1}(x) \neq \frac{1}{sin(x)}$$

but it is notation for the inverse function of the sine function. Another frequently used notation is $\arcsin(x)$

Because $$(\arcsin(x))'  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

$ \sin^{-1} x $ is just a notational difference from $\arcsin x$, the inverse sine function, which represents $ \sin y = x \quad (x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2))$. The derivative is given by,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} [\sin^{-1} x] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

So the limit simplifies to,

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 1 $$